Check arguments in the write system call from userspace to kernel space
I am trying to write a procfs entry from the user space side.
From the kernel side iam using struct file_operations in that .write member which will point to a write funtion in kernel space. The buffer is passed using copy_from_user with a len that is passed wrongly in the write call.
From the userspace I am using base64 command to write into a proc entry since the buffer iam trying to write is a base64 encoded string.
Is there a way to check what arguments and which write call is triggered from userspace side ?

This question is similar to: How to print the userspace stack trace in linux kernelspace. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Concerning the wrong length, passed to the system call: It it perfectly correct for a user space program to write data to the file by chunks, using separate write system call for every chunk. It is up to your kernel module to combine those chunks into a single buffer.

I could trigger a core as a last sort if nothing else could be done.

For the kernel side I will be invalidating/deleting the proc entries that has been created with the previous chunks with previous writes and only use the chunk of the  last write to create the proc entry

If your kernel side expects only a single chunk of the written data, then you could pipe output of base64 e.g. via dd utility for accumulate all data before writing them in a single syscall.

I tried by writing the base64 to a tmp file and trigger another write from the tmp file to proc file then there is only single write with the correct length but I want to understand why this triggers the correct length and not the previous approach where using base64 to directly write a proc file  passes incorrect arguments

"I want to understand why this triggers the correct length and not the previous approach where using base64 to directly write a proc file passes incorrect arguments" - This is what I told you in my second comment. Most likely, base64 writes to the output file in chunks. E.g. it could trigger writing to a file every 3 bytes (when decoding) or every 4 bytes (when encoding).

But I could see it is sending a single chunk of the whole buffered data in sometimes and this is not the scenario every time I try to write the proc file using base64

The fact that base64 sometimes writes the whole data in a single syscall doesn't mean that it should always behave so. In opposite, dd by specification should use single syscall for the full block size (unless the input stream is closed when less than a block size bytes are collected).
